# Did Bakugo become stronger than Midoriya in My Hero Academia: Heroes Rising?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Heroe Academia, Heroes Rising

> Bakugo gets One for All from Midoriya, who still has One for All because this power doesnt leave the user inmediately but lasts for a while. Supposedly when an user gets One for All, he adds his own power to it.

Did Bakugo become stronger than Midoriya in My Hero Academia: Heroes Rising?

Comment: Of course. Giving that Midoriya has no other quirk and Bakugo can enhance his quirk with One for All, he became stronger then Midoriya in terms of ability.
On the other hand, in terms of capability, it is unsure because Bakugo had no time to adapt to his new power so he could lack in skill in how to use his new aquired quirk.

Answer (score 1):

I say perhaps. It depends for how long you are referring to. right at that moment, after an unknown amount of time, it depends.

My reasoning for after an unknown amount of time is because of something that we have heard many times while watching the anime "this is the story of how I became the strongest hero in history". With this it probably means that he has more control over his quirk than Bakugo or something happens to Bakugo later on.

As for after then this. With the One for All quirk it takes time to learn how to use it. For about half of the episodes form the first season (I think) Midoriya spends time trying to use it, and ended out hurting himself, then he learnt how to us the quirk properly.

I am not saying that Midoriya will always be stronger than Bakugo. I am saying that at some points Midoriya will surpass everyone counting Bakugo. There is a chance that Bakugo will be stronger, but it won't be forever

Comment: I wonder if we are going to see that in the story (Midoriya becoming the strongest hero in history) considering that by the time they wrote that, I dont think they had the story completely developed, and in the official polls in Japan and in United States Bakugo became more popular than Midoriya. I wouldnt be surprised if they retcon that idea

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some misunderstanding of how you think the movie ended, or you probably did not wait till the end of the movie. Towards the ending of the movie (MHA: Heroes Rising)

> while Deku was talking to  all might, One for all came back to Midoriya and the explanation that all might gave was that apparently, the previous wielders of the quirk deemed Midoriya truly worthy and hence Midoriya remained the successor. This means that although Bakugo was able to momentarily use it during the battle, he no longer possesses or even remembers that the event occured becausse the transfer was interrupted and did not complete.

> Now this is my opinion, during the fight, Bakugo did infact surpass Midoriya because his abilities where heightened to crazy levels and he also possesed the extra stockpiled strength and speed perks. The tricky part tho was in his overall control since it took a greater toll on him and thats to be expected since using the quirk at 100% has disastrous backlash on those who havent mastered it.